# bash scrolling after bottom of terminal copies background color to the entire line below. (eg. prompt with background color)

Tags: bash, ps1

```
calculate_prompt1()
{
    host="my-linux"
    git_branch="a very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long prompt"
    prompt="@$host \\w : \[$(tput bold)$(tput setab 1)$(tput setaf 7)\]${git_branch}\[$(tput sgr0)\]\$ "
    export PS1="$prompt"
}

PROMPT_COMMAND="calculate_prompt1;"
```

keep pressing enter until you reach the bottom of your terminal and keep pressing enter. you will see that the background color of the prompt starts going past the prompt.

why?

Whats the fix?

Thank you!

Comment: prompt_command doesn't need to change PS1 just echo it, `set -x` may explain why

Comment: My vote is for a bug in `bash`. A similar prompt in `zsh` doesn't display the same behavior.

Comment: Setting `PS1`, rather than outputting it, is the correct thing to do from `PROMPT_COMMAND`. (Exporting it, though, is unnecessary.)

Comment: what is PS1 before ?

Comment: Note that this isn't really a multi-line prompt, since it displays on one line if your terminal is wide enough; there are no explicit newlines to force it onto multiple lines. (And when the terminal *is* wide enough, there are no anomalies.)

Comment: Specifically, it looks like the problem occurs when the terminal has to scroll up to display the rest of the line, then reset the graphics mode with `tput sgr0`. It appears to apply that to show the final space of the prompt, but then revert to the background color in effect before it scrolled. Note that if you type something, then backspace, the color clears until the next line. I don't know enough about how `bash` interacts with the terminal to speculate further. IMO, it's worth sending this exact example to `bug-bash@gnu.org` and see what the maintainer has to say.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul I put set -x but couldn't find anything useful to resolve my issue.

Comment: @chepner You are right. I noticed that the backspace clears the color. Does the bug-bash@gnu.org take email from anybody or do I have to register

Comment: From any one; you can run `bashbug` to get a bug report template to fill out and e-mail.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: here was not useful, in case an example how to debug prompt command : `PROMPT_COMMAND="set -x;calculate_prompt1 2>&1 | od -c;"`, otherwise other workaround, less clean than solution `bind '"\C-m": "\C-j \C-h"'`

Answer (score 0):

as per @chepner suggestion I emailed bug-bash@gnu.org

So far this seems to be a bug in bash (even the latest version 4.4 has it)

The workaround they gave me, which seems to work so far is to put

```
$(tput el)
```

after

```
$(tput sgr0)
```

so the example in the question becomes

```
prompt="@$host \\w : \[$(tput bold)$(tput setab 1)$(tput setaf 7)\]${git_branch}\[$(tput sgr0)$(tput el)\]\$ "
```

I will paste the email I got for completeness

> I get the same with '4.4.12(1)-release' too, but it doesn't seem
>   related to Bash or the prompt. I can get it with just a printf, the
>   colored part just needs to get wrapped by the end of line.
>
> printf "%100s $(tput setab 1)colored part$(tput sgr0) normal again\n"
>
> If the screen scrolls, the background color on the last character gets
>   copied to the next line. At least one way to work around that seems to
>   be to clear the end of the line after the colored part ends, by
>   putting "$(tput el)" after "$(tput sgr0)". You probably don't have
>   anything to the right of the cursor at that point, so it'll only reset
>   the color.

kudos to people monitoring bug-bash@gnu.org as they were really quick to reply